# after inputting the values how can i display the values under one bracket e.g "{6,7,8,9}

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

int n;

cout << "No. of values : ";

cin >> n;

int array[n];

for (int i=0; i<n; i++)

{

cin >> array[i];


}

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Use a loop and `cout`.  Have you made an attempt at outputting the values?

Comment: Please consider to pick a [better resource for learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Your code is not valid c++

Comment: `int array[n];` is a compiler extension that is best being avoided, use `std::vector` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use std::cout like :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int n;

    cout << "No. of values : ";

    cin >> n;

    int array[n];

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)

    {
        cin >> array[i];
        if(i ==0)
            std::cout<<"{" <<array[i];
        else if(i == n-1)
            std::cout<<","<<array[i]<<"}";
        else
            std::cout<<","<<array[i];
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `cin >> n; int array[n];` is a VLA and is non-standard. I would suggest using `std::vector<int>`.

Answer (score 0):

@mystic's answer uses arrays, which works fine.  You can also use vector.  There are more advanced methods of iterating over a vector, but I have not included that here to keep it simple.

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> intVector{};

    int n;
    int input;

    cout << "No. of values : ";
    cin >> n;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> input;
        intVector.push_back(input);
    }

    // Print out the array
    cout << "{";

    for(int i = 0; i < intVector.size(); i++) {
        cout << intVector[i];
        // print out the comma, except for the last number
        if(i < intVector.size() - 1) {
            cout << ", ";
        }
    }
    cout << "}" << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

If you want to use an iterator for printing the array, you can replace the print loop with this code:

```c++
    // Print out the array
    cout << "{";
    for(auto i=intVector.begin(); i!=intVector.end(); ++i) {
        if (i != intVector.begin()) {
            cout << ", ";
        }
        cout << *i;
    }
    cout << "}" << endl;
```